# TFLite Model Maker Object Detection Error

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to do a custom object detection for raspberry pi using tensorflow lite. I saw tensorflow's [video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZyFYniGUsw&t=340s) and decided to give it a try. I used the [google collab link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/khanhlvg/tflite_raspberry_pi/blob/main/object_detection/Train_custom_model_tutorial.ipynb#scrollTo=35BJmtVpAP_n) provided in the video. However, running the first block of code, this error occured:

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXwck.png)

Can anyone give me a solution or an alternative?

Comment: Kindly install the dependencies required for Tensorflow Lite on your Raspberry Pi. And check your pip and setup tools are updated or not by using this commands.
`sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools`